# Talend Error: Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory

Tags: java, amazon-s3, talend

I am using Talend to load some data from Redshift, then upload it to S3 and then Redshift again.

The logic is tRedshiftInput -> tRedshiftOutputBulkExec

However, I am getting this error:

> Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:136)     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.(AmazonS3Client.java:481)     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.(AmazonS3Client.java:461)     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.(AmazonS3Client.java:443)     at momox.ga2redshift_tvvisits_inside_0_1.GA2Redshift_TVvisits_Inside.tGoogleAnalyticsInput_1Process(GA2Redshift_TVvisits_Inside.java:1516)  at momox.ga2redshift_tvvisits_inside_0_1.GA2Redshift_TVvisits_Inside.runJobInTOS(GA2Redshift_TVvisits_Inside.java:2082)     at momox.ga2redshift_tvvisits_inside_0_1.GA2Redshift_TVvisits_Inside.runJob(GA2Redshift_TVvisits_Inside.java:1911)  at momox.ga2redshift_tvvisits_loop_0_1.GA2Redshift_TVvisits_Loop.tRedshiftInput_1Process(GA2Redshift_TVvisits_Loop.java:1149)   at momox.ga2redshift_tvvisits_loop_0_1.GA2Redshift_TVvisits_Loop.tRedshiftRow_2Process(GA2Redshift_TVvisits_Loop.java:567)  at momox.ga2redshift_tvvisits_loop_0_1.GA2Redshift_TVvisits_Loop$2.run(GA2Redshift_TVvisits_Loop.java:2613) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactory    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)    ... 10 more

The libraries I have for the job are:

```
aws-java-sdk-1.10.52.jar
cimt.talendcomp.gaanalytics-2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
commons-codec-1.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
httpclient-4.5.2.jar
httpclient-4.5.3.jar
httpcore-4.3.3.jar
jackson-annotations-2.5.3.jar
jackson-core-2.5.3.jar
jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar
joda-time-2.8.1.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
routines.jar
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have httpclient-4.5.2.jar & 4.5.3.jar in classpath. It is not advised to have both version in classpath. Take out one and try.

Comment: I tried it.. it still throws the same error..